# Does Scrollr = Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Are Scrollr and WOW just plain javascript? If so, why does everyone refer to it as if it's its own thing?

I've looked at a few tutorials, but at this point, it's all over my head, but I'm getting there. I've just started learning basic javascript (learning about arrays right now), and in my javascript handbook, it doesn't mention anything about Scrollr.

Comment: They are Javascript plugins created by 3rd parties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if it's a 3rd party thing, that means I have to find it, download it, do I have to buy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of javascript. Skrollr is a javascript library for doing scrolling animations. A javascript book probably wouldn't mention Skrollr if it's talking about pure javascript. Skrollr is a tool that you can use to make your webpages have some fancy animations when you scroll on the page. There a literally hundreds, if not thousands of these kinds of libraries all over the web. However, some are known more than others. Similar libraries using jQuery can do the same things. Who knows, once you get the hang of javascript, maybe you'll be making your own.

Answer (score 0):

They are both JavaScript libraries. Which means that yes, it's made of plain JavaScript. In the same way you make a `.js` file of function declarations and call them in another `.js` file. They are a bit more complicated than that, but the idea is the same.

Comment: So in other words, if I'm learning (or learn) javascript, then I shouldn't need the libraries, I can just write my own, correct? I looked at the code inside. Seems pretty complex. over 1500 lines just to manipulate some css animations via the scroll bar position. I'm surprised it takes that much effort.

Comment: @RyanSteiger That's Correct. Although a library I would recommend is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). JavaScript libraries can be helpful because you don't have to build something complex from scratch. You can use one that is high quality and has been tested thoroughly. For now get to know how to use JavaScript naively (without libraries), because all JavaScript libraries are made with native JavaScript, you will not have much trouble using them (if they have good documentation). For now, get used to normal JavaScript. There is no need to use libraries to learn the language.